# Angular re-create <router-outlet> component with the same route and different param

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like to change reload my component without change the param of the route.
I explain with some code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard', component: Dashboard},
  {
    path: '', component: Main,
    children: [
      {path: ':scope', component: ScopeChildren,}
    ]
  }
];
```

My problem is that when I change only the ":scope" in the route, the component "ScopeChildren" should be re-initialized, but actually is not happening.

Main component html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I search online and I found the re-use strategy but actually this solution is not good because this solution is going to reload all the application and not only the ScopeChildren component.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the LifeCycle and Angular Change Detection Tree to understand better how the Angular framework works.

However, you must subscribe to the ParamsMap observer of ActivatedRoute and manually reset the component state and set it to the new value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I think that I know about the lifeciclye and how it works, but I would like to avoid to use the subscribe in the paramsmap because this will require a lot of change in my code (this is a monolith project without routing that I'm converting to a route-lazy-way).
There is no way to force the reload of the component when a param change?